# Applying correction for multiple tests to get p-adjusted value

Tags: r

I have done multiple linear regression tests and got result. Here are a few rows of result:

```
Name    estimate    std.error   statistic   p.value Note
A1  0.0856767524298681  0.0126892271621709  6.7519283353432 1.33883410848243e-10    protein
A2  0.0369509779463753  0.00547265553056216 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848245e-10    protein
A3  0.0323211629170586  0.00478695289875522 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848246e-10    protein
A4  0.00213432164701004 0.000316105494757381    6.75192833534319    1.33883410848246e-10    protein
A5  0.010932202013597   0.00161912293357321 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848247e-10    Retrovirus
```

I want to run correction for multiple tests and get an additional column for `adjusted p-value` using `p.adjust` function. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `with(df1, p.adjust(p.value, method = 'bonferroni', n = n1))` where `n1 <- 5` ( not sure)

Comment: @akrun, post as answer?  I don't think `n=` is necessary as `n=length(p)` by default?  By the way, Holm (the default method) dominates Bonferroni (except for familiarity) so I would just use `df1 <- transform(df1, p.adjust = p.adjust(p.value))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose df is your original data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_add_padj <- df %>% mutate("adjusted p-value" = p.adjust(p.value, method="fdr"))
```

method can be fdr, bonferroni and etc.

Comment: (1) tidyverse is overkill (2) it's best IMO to avoid column names that aren't legal variable names (e.g. including spaces, -), but the general idea is fine.

Comment: Thank you, but all adjusted p-values are 1. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: That is strange. Is the pvalue column numeric? Can you post your code here?

Comment: Here is the code I am using: library(tidyverse)
df_add_padj <- resul.csv %>% mutate("adjusted_p-value" = p.adjust(p.value, method="fdr")) and the value column is numeric. I checked while importing.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine with me. Not sure what's going on. It may related to the distribution of your pvalue.

Comment: I noticed when I change p.value column from factor to numeric using df$p.value<-as.numeric(factor(df$p.value)). It converts p-values to weird numbers., e.g., 1.33883410848243e-10 p-value gets converted to 28119 after I change it to numeric.

Comment: You need to do as.numeric(as.character(df$p.value)). Directly changing from factor to numeric will not work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I got this warning:Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion. It works despite the warning but I was wondering if it needs to be fixed.

Comment: This warning is telling you there are NA or Inf in your pvalue. It won't affect the results.